# Is there a better way to handle button behavior than a control-ID-to-function map?

Tags: c++, winapi, button

I'm coding a windows app in C++ and am in the dark on standard practice for streamlining button behavior. I've come up with a pretty decent solution on my own.

- A global button-control-id-to-function map:

  `std::map<int, VOID (*)()> buttonMap;`
- Registration in the button creation function:

  ```
    HWND CreateButton(int controlID, VOID (*)() func, LPCTSTR text, int x, int y, HWND parent) {
        buttonMap[controlID] = func;

        //creation stuff...
    }
  ```
- Invocation in Window Process:

  ```
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (HIWORD(wParam)) {
        case BN_CLICKED:
            if (buttonMap.count(LOWORD(wParam))) {
                std::invoke(buttonMap[LOWORD(wParam)]);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
  ```

I want to know if I'm missing out on an already-established solution to managing button behavior. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The overall approach is sound (I've used very similar things myself), I would however both switch to using an std::unordered_map and to using unordered_map::find then testing the returned iterator. That way you only need perform the lookup once.

I would also likely change my function signature to taking parameters (the owning window handle if nothing else)

```
      case BN_CLICKED:
{
  if(std::map<int, VOID (*)(HWND)>::const_iterator iter { buttonMap.find(LOWORD(wParam))}; buttonMap.cend() != iter)
    std::invoke(iter->second, hWnd);
}
```